# How to search particular element under some parent element without using Index of element

Tags: cypress

I have a search box and when I search some Device I get results of all devices matching string, e.g. if I search AppleiPhone XS, a result I get will be Apple iPhone XS MAX, Apple iPhone XS DEMO DATA, Apple iPhone XS.

Now I want to click on the link which is below Apple iPhone XS, but without using Index of that element i.e. without using eq. As some time result for other devices will give only 1 output.

[image]

```html
<div class="c-loadingIndicator-containment l-vertical-scrollParent">
    <div class="l-vertical-list u-p+ ng-scope" ng-if="offeringsController.offerOptionViewModel.length > 0">
                <div class="c-selectableOption-body">
                    <div class="c-selectableOption-meta" ng-class="{'u-flexTop': selectableOptionController.useIdHeader}">
                        <div ng-if="!selectableOptionController.useIdHeader" class="c-selectableOption-title ng-scope">
                            <span title="Apple iPhone XS MAX" class="ng-binding">Apple iPhone XS MAX</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="c-selectableOption-extras">
                        <div class="c-quickviewButton c-button c-button--link ng-binding ng-scope" ng-if="selectableOptionController.showQuickView" ng-click="selectableOptionController.quickViewClick(selectableOptionController.id)" ng-bind="::selectableOptionController.UILocaleKeys.QUICK_VIEW | i18n">quick view</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                <div class="c-selectableOption-body">
                    <div class="c-selectableOption-meta" ng-class="{'u-flexTop': selectableOptionController.useIdHeader}">
                        <div ng-if="!selectableOptionController.useIdHeader" class="c-selectableOption-title ng-scope">
                            <span title="Apple iPhone XS" class="ng-binding">Apple iPhone XS</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="c-selectableOption-extras">
                        <div class="c-quickviewButton c-button c-button--link ng-binding ng-scope" ng-if="selectableOptionController.showQuickView" ng-click="selectableOptionController.quickViewClick(selectableOptionController.id)" ng-bind="::selectableOptionController.UILocaleKeys.QUICK_VIEW | i18n">quick view</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have any control over the markup; could you add attributes to make it easy to select the items you want? For example, `[data-qa="quick link"][data-qa-value="Apple iPhone XS"]`

Comment: @jonrsharpe: No I don't have any control over markup.

Comment: Then you'll probably have to find the header by text then use https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/parent.html to go "up".

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a regex to [`cy.contains`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains.html#Syntax) that will contain end-of-line anchor.

```js
// As your `selector` you'll need to use the closest wrapping element
// containing the target text else the regex's `$` will not work here.
// (the \s accounts for potential whitespace around the text)
cy.contains('span', /apple iphone xs\s*$/i)
    // get common ancestor
    .closest('.c-selectableOption-body')
    // find the quick view button
    .contains('.c-selectableOption-extras', /quick view/i);
```

In fact, you don't need to use any `selector` at all, which will get the closest elem by default (you could also use `*` as the `selector`, which would act the same):

```js
cy.contains(/apple iphone xs\s*$/i)
```